# Assign already created variable to new variable in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to assign already created variable to the new vector.
eg.
Suppose df1 & df2  are my two variables which are already created.

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 2, 3), v2 = c("a", "b", "c"))
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 4, 3), v2 = c("a", "c", "c"))
```

& i wanted to first match the name from df3 column V1 and then assign this to matching variable.

```
df3 <- data.frame(V1 = c('df1','df2','df3'), v2 = c("b", "b", "c"))

I want to do this in loop.

df1<-df1

I have used df1<-eval(parse(df3$V1[[1]])) but not understand.

Anybody know how to do this??
```

Comment: What is the logic to get `df3` as output?

Comment: i am trying to assign the same name data-frame to the first row of df3 if matching.

Comment: The way to solve this is to put all these data frames into a list and use list indices or list item names. Do *not* use separate variables for this. And when you find yourself using `eval(parse(…))` or the equivalent, chances are your approach is unnecessarily convoluted.